# qapps runs well but breakpoint sometimes generates segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, segmentation-fault, qthread

I have a qApp that generates a segmentation fault only when a breakpoint is inserted in the code (I can put it at different places) and only after 4-5 breakpoint stops.   Do I have a problem with my code or is this a DBG bug. the method is part of a QThread Class.

Basically what I did is i  took the mandlebrot example, and have 3 instances of it in my program.  So the program would look like a mainwindow that has 3 mandlebrot widgets in it, one besides the other.   Is it possible that GDB doesnt support debugging qthread subclasses that are instantiated multiple times or is it thread-unsafe to do so.  I dont have any problems at run-time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I Always debug multiple instances of a same object that is of type thread with GDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861876/can-i-always-debug-multiple-instances-of-a-same-object-that-is-of-type-thread-wit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you have unsynchronized access to some object in your code and breakpoints are happily allows you to see the problem.

Comment: do you mean multiple threads trying to acces objects at the same time?

Comment: actually, at the moment this occurs, nothing outside the class interacts with it. Only the constructor gets called and this is done without any resources that are external to the class itself.